# Does f string formatting cast a variable into a string?

Tags: python, string

I was working with f-strings, and I am fairly new to python. My question is does the f-string formatting cast a variable(an integer) into a string?

```
number = 10
print(f"{number} is not a string")
```

Is `number` cast into a string?

Comment: Not 'cast', no. But yes, the `f"..."` string format produces a string with any `{...}` turned into strings inside the result. See the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) for details on how integers and other values are converted to a string for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, see https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#specification By default it will call `str()` but you can use `!r` or `!a` to use `repr()` or `ascii()` instead

Comment: Actually, what do *you* think 'cast' means here? Python doesn't have casting, not by the commonly understood technical definition of casting, because Python variables have no type.

Comment: I've closed this question as *unclear*, because there are multiple interpretations possible interpretations to what you are asking, as evidenced by the answers posted so far. Please edit your question to clarify what exactly you mean by 'casting'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f"..."` expressions *format* values to strings, integrate the result into a larger string and return that result. That's not quite the same as 'casting'<sup>*</sup>.

`number` is an expression here, one that happens to produce an integer object. The integer is then formatted to a string, by calling the `__format__` method on that object, with the first argument, a string containing a *format specifier*, left empty:

```
>>> number = 10
>>> number.__format__('')
'10'
```

We'll get to the format specifier later.

The original integer object, `10`, didn't change here, it remains an integer, and `.__format__()` just returned a new object, a string:

```
>>> f"{number} is not a string"
'10 is not a string'
>>> number
10
>>> type(number)
int
```

There are more options available to influence the output by adding a format specifier to the `{...}` placeholder, after a `:`. You can see what exact options you have by reading the [Format Specification Mini Language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec); this documents what the Python standard types might expect as format specifiers.

For example, you could specify that the number should be left-aligned in a string that's at least 5 characters wide, with the specifier `<5`:

```
>>> f"Align the number between brackets: [{number:<5}]"
'Align the number between brackets: [10   ]'
```

The `{number:<5}` part tells Python to take the output of `number.__format__("<5")` and use that as the string value to combine with the rest of the string, in between the `[` and `]` parts.

This still doesn't change what the `number` variable references, however.

---

<sup>*</sup>: In technical terms, *casting* means *changing the type of a variable*. This is not something you do in Python because Python variables *don't have a type*. Python variables are references to objects, and in Python it is those objects that have a type. You can change what a variable references, e.g. `number = str(number)` would replace the integer with a string object, but that's not casting either.

Answer (score 2):

You can test it yourself quite easily

```
number = 10
print(f"{number} is not a string")

print(type(number))
# output is integer
```

Comment: The output is `<class 'int'>`, actually, not 'integer'. But that's nitpicking.

Comment: for those who care about the ancient python past :

$  python2.7
WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 

>>> number = 3
>>> type(number)
int

Answer (score 0):

If u can't understand f string or other soln dosent make any sense then try this.
This will help you integrate a variable(integer/char) in a string.

```
a = "blah blah blah {} blah blah ".format(integer_value)
print(a)
```